# PHP and mysql proc

Tags: php

If php code like below how it's like as mysql stored procedure equivalent. If any links tutorial on advance stored procedure mysql please put.

```
$sql = " SELECT  a,b FROM  j ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $sql_update = "UPDATE b set a=" . $row['a'] . "'";
        mysql_query($sql_update);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for.

Comment: what i mean are like this
if mysql proc like this
create proc x()
x=select a into a_proc,b into b_proc from j
   if x record more then  0 
      fetch x query
        update b set a =a_proc
      end fetch
   end if
I try a lot but still don't work.I just want to know the proper way to it

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty complete example here.  The article is about Qcodo, but there's a good example using the `mysqli` API.

http://amountaintop.com/php-5-and-mysql-5-stored-procedures-error-and-solution-qcodo

You can't do it with the `mysql` extension.  Stored procedures can return multiple result sets, so you must use the `mysqli` extension.  You need to call `mysqli_multi_query()` and continue to loop over result sets until you have read them all.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into mysqli and use prepared statements?